# searching for a string that contains 2 or more known sub strings

Tags: python

That's my approach

```
title = ('one two three four')


if 'one' and 'three' in title:
    print('Found')
else:
    print('not found')
```

but it always returns `found`

I want it to return found only when both of the substrings exist together, not one of them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That’s because it checks conditions on both side of `and`.
Instead you should be doing;

```py
if "one" in title and "three" in title:
    print("Found")
else:
    print("Not Found")
```

Answer (score 3):

Alternately to the answer by @FishballNooodles, we can use `all` and a generator expression to solve this.

```
if all(word in title for word in ('one', 'three')):
    print('found')
else:
    print('Not found')
```

The chief benefit of this approach is how easy it is to extend the list of words that have to be included.

Another slightly more esoteric approach would be to leverage the fact that `str.index` raises a `ValueError` exception if the substring cannot be found. In this case we have to use `any` because `str.index` might return `0` which will be interpreted as false in a boolean context and will let `all` exit early.

```
try:
    any(map(title.index, ['one', 'three']))
    print('Found')
except ValueError:
    print('Not found')
```

If mapping `title.index` to each of the substrings completes, that means all of them were found, and we can print `'Found'`. Otherwise the `except ValueError` clause will print `'Not found'`.